# what is `...` in c macro function?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Hi I've been reading through a c library, and I've encountered macro functions such as this:

```c
#define TF_LITE_KERNEL_LOG(context, ...)           \
  do {                                             \  
    (context)->ReportError((context),__VA_ARGS__); \
} while (false)
```

I don't exactly get the use of `...` as one of the parameters. Could anyone see what is it's purpose? Is it used to ignore other arguments if the function is called in a way like this?  : `TF_LITE_KERNEL_LOG(context, arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Comment: @Dai macro, not function.

Comment: @Dai that's preprocessor stuff, not related at all with a variadic function.

Comment: Notably, variadic functions have (unfortunately) always been part of C, but variadic macros were introduced in the year 1999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the variadic arguments marker: the `__VA_ARGS__` are replaced with the rest of the arguments given to the macro, like e.g. in `printf()`, so

`TF_LITE_KERNEL_LOG(context, arg1, arg2, arg3)` will be like:

`context->ReportError(context, arg1, arg2, arg3)`.